# ¿Cómo quito la advertencia "Image with has either width or height modified, but not the other." en Next.js?

Tags: next.js

Esta advertencia es bastante molesta en la consola y no se cómo quitarla. Ya probé agregando la propiedad layout="responsive" que me recomendó el chatGPT pero me aparece otra advertencia que dice "Image with src "/logo.png" has legacy prop "layout". Did you forget to run the codemod?"

```
<Image 
  src={'/logo.png'}
  width={200}
  height={100}
  alt="Logo"
/>
```